# Classical inheritance with Object.create() and...typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

I was looking through MDN's doc on Object.create() to see how it works while looking through someones code. But here's what I'm wondering now, as a typescript newbie.

How can I get their example to work with typescript while not using a class?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#classical_inheritance_with_object.create

In a ts file, I can't find a way around this error without using js classes: `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

EDIT:

I come close if I do something like this:

```
function Shape(this: any) {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x: any, y: any) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle(this: any) {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

//If you don't set Rectangle.prototype.constructor to Rectangle,
//it will take the prototype.constructor of Shape (parent).
//To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Rectangle (child).
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

const rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

Comment: `Object.create` is awfully typed in *es5.d.ts*. You basically have to use type assertions if you want to use it. But really, when writing TypeScript, you just should always use `class` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Oh...this seems to do it...

```
function Shape(this: any) {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x: any, y: any) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.log('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle(this: any) {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

//If you don't set Rectangle.prototype.constructor to Rectangle,
//it will take the prototype.constructor of Shape (parent).
//To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Rectangle (child).
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

const rect = new (Rectangle as any)();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```